# Is the base for bloodletting in the Talmud purely "scientific" or traditional?

Tags: halacha-theory, medicine, science, pikuachnefesh-danger-life

[Bloodletting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloodletting) ([הקזת דם](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%96%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%9D)) was a commonplace medical procedure in the Mishnaic times (see Shabbos 129).
It is widely accepted that the ancient healers believed that:

> "...  many diseases were caused by plethoras, or overabundances, in the blood... "Bleeding" a patient to health was modeled on the process of menstruation. Hippocrates believed that menstruation functioned to "purge women of bad humors". During the Roman Empire, the Greek physician Galen, who subscribed to the teachings of Hippocrates, advocated physician-initiated bloodletting... The Talmud recommended a specific day of the week and days of the month for bloodletting... (WIKI ibid)"

Rambam started to treat the bloodletting with more caution (Deos 4,14):

> "לא ירגיל אדם עצמו להקיז דם תמיד, ולא יקיז דם אלא אם היה צריך לו ביותר; ...".

We also know that hurting oneself is a transgression, and today the bloodletting would be forbidden after proven seriously wrong. The Sages themselves saw a great danger in it.

I wonder if the Sages' practice of bloodletting was based purely on the medical customs of the leading "scientists" of their times, or had some Jewish traditional roots?

Please notice, this question is *not* about the benefits/dangers of bloodletting, but about its origin.

Comment: Why do you wonder about bloodletting and not the myriads of other forms of unsound medical advice mentioned by Chazal?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think BL is the most common and the most recognized with the Rabbis. Maybe there Is a medical tradition from Moses that we're unaware of.

Comment: From: https://www.rasmussen.edu/degrees/health-sciences/blog/surprising-health-benefits-of-donating-blood/ - 2. Giving blood can reduce harmful iron stores
One in every two hundred people in the U.S. is affected by a condition called hemochromatosis and most don’t even know it, according to Patenaude. Hemochromatosis is a disease that causes an iron overload and is labeled as the most common genetic disease among Caucasians by the Mayo Clinic.

Comment: 3. Giving blood may lower your risk of suffering a heart attack
Donating blood at least once a year could reduce your risk of a heart attack by 88 percent, according to a study conducted by the American Journal of Epidemiology.* This relates to the iron issue again, says Dr. David Dragoo, healthcare expert at Money Crashers.

Comment: 4. Giving blood may reduce your risk of developing cancer
In an average, completely healthy person, the link between giving blood and decreased cancer risk is slim. But research does support a reduced risk of cancer for blood donors with different maladies, one of which is hemochromatosis.

Comment: Phlebotomy (the process of drawing blood) was found to be an iron-reduction method that is associated with lower cancer risk and mortality, according to a study published by the Journal of the National Cancer Institute. The study focused on patients affected by peripheral arterial disease (PAD), which the Mayo Clinic describes as a common circulatory problem. PAD patients who regularly donated blood had a lower risk of developing cancer than those who did not.

Comment: 5. Giving blood can help your liver stay healthy
Another danger of iron overload is the health of your liver. “In recent years, nonalcoholic fatty liver disease (NAFLD), the hepatic expression of metabolic syndrome, has reached epidemic proportions,” reports the National Center for Biotechnology Information.

Research has linked too much iron with NAFLD, Hepatitis C and other liver diseases and infections. Though there are many other factors involved in these problems, donating blood can help relieve some of those iron stores and avoid extra issues in your liver.

Comment: @Loewian thank you for copying the internet. Everything you quoted was unknown to the ancients. And the question was not about the benefits of BL at all. It was about the sources for that practice - was it [pseudo-]scientific or traditional.

Comment: It's often difficult to understand some of the medical procedures the Talmud recommends. Apparently, this is what worked at the time. Current medical science would consider many of these practices dangerous or not dangerous. (E.g. - the rule of not drinking water left under the bed overnight is no longer dangerous. It's a mystery to some notable rabbanim as to why we still prohibit fish & meat mixture these days.) Blood-letting was considered common as recently as 40 - 50 years ago. Europeans used leeches to suck out blood. I gather that some Hassidm still use them.

Comment: IIRC Maharal held that it’s forbidden to quote medical advice from the Gemara because it’s probably wrong.

Comment: @DonielF It was someone relatively recent. I'll see what I can find on that aspect. Perhaps there's an article on that with the "Association of Jewish Orthodox Scientists"? I THINK that's what this org. is named.

Comment: I think that for beris, metzitzah is more than the then-medicine of blood letting. No proof, which is why this is only a comment, but here's the argument.

Comment: If a beris is done on Shabbos and there are scraps left that don't invalidate the milah (tzitzin she'einan me'aqvin), the mohel can go back and cut them off as long as he's still doing the beris. Otherwise, it's a second surgery on Shabbos -- as the beris is kosher as-is. If the mohel is still doing metzitzah, he is not considered "finished". But if he is applying the cumin compress he is done. So, metzitzah is part of the beris in ways other medicine isn't. To me it appears it had two rolls.

Comment: @DanF: Yes, it's the Association of Jewish Orthodox Scientists - AOJS. https://www.aojs.org

Comment: @micha because metzitza is internal and cumin is external (only external is considered פירש). It is indeed different but still fundamentally mistaken. (And anyway your claim that we go back even during metzitza is debated.)

Comment: @DoubleAAL Thanks. I see the MB repeats the Ran's safeiq, but the Arukh haShulchan (my rebbe taught us to use AhS as poseiq acharon) doesn't worry about the side I gave. Meanwhile, there is a related machloqes -- if the same person has to do metzitzah and peri'ah.

Comment: Still, I wonder about why then we still require metzitzah with a pipette. We could have ruled like the Chasam Sofer, and permitted using gauze. (A ruling so surprising the Maharam Shik couldn't believe his rebbe said it, and thought it was a false rumor. But we have it in writing.) Lehalakhah the alternative to metzitzah bepeh is to use a pipette, which is in reality still a kind of metzitzah bepeh.

Comment: And in terms of the overall point... Can we tell those from communities who hold that metzitzah must be literallly bepeh that they MUST pick sides on the unknown, and run the risk of not performing beris milah?